# Pegar última div de uma div

Tags: javascript

Considerando essa estrutura:

```
<div id="PAI">
  <div uniqid="1" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="2" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="3" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="4" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="5" class="filho">A</div>
</div>
```

preciso pegar a div de número de `uniqid = 5` ou seja, sempre, a última da div com id `PAI` como fazer?

Comment: último elemento/objeto ou última "div" ? pode acontecer de existir outros elementos dentro de uma div, exemplo, um <span>, uma ancora <a>, um row <hr>

Comment: @DanielOmine o último objeto vai seguir o modelo que demonstrei acima sendo sempre uma div com tais atributos mas elas sempre estarão recheadas de outros elementos..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes usar [`element.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild) que quando aplicado ao elemento pai dá o que queres, o ultimo elemento.

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rz7o7u0/

```js
var pai = document.getElementById("PAI");
var ultimoFilho = pai.lastElementChild;
ultimoFilho.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

```html
<div id="PAI">
    <div uniqid="1" class="filho">A</div>
    <div uniqid="2" class="filho">A</div>
    <div uniqid="3" class="filho">A</div>
    <div uniqid="4" class="filho">A</div>
    <div uniqid="5" class="filho">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar [**`document#querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

---

#### Obtendo o último elemento pela classe **`.filho`** :

```js
var last = document.querySelector(".filho:last-child");
last.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="PAI">
  <div uniqid="1" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="2" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="3" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="4" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="5" class="filho">A</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Obtendo o último div dentro de **`#PAI`** :

```js
var last = document.querySelector("#PAI div:last-child");
last.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="PAI">
  <div uniqid="1" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="2" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="3" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="4" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="5" class="filho">A</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Obtendo o elemento pelo `uniqid=5` :

```js
var last= document.querySelector("[uniqid='5']");
last.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="PAI">
  <div uniqid="1" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="2" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="3" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="4" class="filho">A</div>
  <div uniqid="5" class="filho">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que `.querySelector` funciona também pra nós, i.e. também dá pra fazer `document.getElementById('PAI').querySelector(':last-child')`; isso é útil se você já tiver uma referência a `#PAI` à mão.